# How to implement the method "+ (BOOL)resolveClassMethod:(SEL)sel"

Tags: objective-c, runtime

I'm learning runtime, when I code this:

```
@implementation Son
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
    [self performSelector:@selector(sel) withObject:nil];
    }

    return self;
}

id dynamicMethodIMP(id self, SEL _cmd)
{
    NSLog(@"%s:dynamic method",__FUNCTION__);
    return @"1";
}
+ (BOOL)resolveInstanceMethod:(SEL)sel {
    class_addMethod(self.class, sel, (IMP)(dynamicMethodIMP), "@@:");
    [super resolveInstanceMethod:sel];
    return YES;
}
@end
```

It's running very well.
But when I code this:

```
    @implementation Son
    id dynamicMethodIMP(id self, SEL _cmd)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s:dynamic method",__FUNCTION__);
        return @"1";
    }
    + (BOOL)resolveClassMethod:(SEL)sel {
        class_addMethod(self.class, sel, (IMP)(dynamicMethodIMP), "@@:");
        [super resolveClassMethod:sel];
        return YES;
    }    
    @end
    //Other file
    [Son performSelector:@selector(sel) withObject:nil];
```

It crashed with:

> +[Son sel]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10da8a588

What should I do to implement the method `+ (BOOL)resolveClassMethod:(SEL)sel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `self.class` with `object_getClass`

```
+ (BOOL)resolveClassMethod:(SEL)sel {
    class_addMethod(object_getClass(self), sel, (IMP)(dynamicMethodIMP), "@@:");
    [super resolveClassMethod:sel];
    return YES;
}
```

Reason:

> `object_getClass` will return meta class if parameter is a class object。

If you read Chinese, you can read my [blog](https://blog.csdn.net/hello_hwc/article/details/49687543) to see more details about meta class.